# return multiple map<string,string> in java

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, hashset

I'm trying to move void method to it's own class and return the map's key value pair (debitCardDetails, creditCardDetails). What is the right way to return the multiple map and extract in parent class or do i need to merger the `Map<String, Map<String, String>> result`and return the result ?

```
public class CardService {

    public void serviceCall(List<CardImplementation> mapDetails) {

        final Map<String, String> debitCardDetailsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        final Map<String, String> creditCardDetailsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        /*code implementation */
        debitCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
        debitCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "BofA");
        debitCardDetailsMap.put("rank", "2");

        creditCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
        creditCardDetailsMap.put("number","23345");
        creditCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "citi");
    }
}
```

parentClass will look something like this

```
public class ServiceClass {

CardService cardService = new CardService();
  if ( debitCardDetailsMap.size() > 0 ) {
      checkAccount(debitCardDetailsMap);
  }
  if ( creditCardDetailsMap.size()>0 ) {
     checkScore(creditCardDetailsMap);
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to return both debitCardDetailsMap's AND creditCardDetailsMap's key-value pair, am i right ?

Comment: you can add both map in a list and return that list.

Comment: Why maps? Why not create classes for these things?

Comment: You are missing an abstraction here. Card needs to be a separate abstract class from which debitcard and credicard can be subclassed. Then your map reduces to map of just cards.

Comment: @Mad-D - did you try my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a carddetailsDTO object and play around with the DTO. Something like below.

```
mport java.util.Map;

public class CardDetailsDTO {

    private Map<String,String> debitCardDetails;

    private Map<String,String> creditCardDetails;

    public Map<String,String> getCreditCardDetails() {
        return creditCardDetails;
    }

    public void setCreditCardDetails(Map<String,String> creditCardDetails) {
        this.creditCardDetails = creditCardDetails;
    }

    public Map<String,String> getDebitCardDetails() {
        return debitCardDetails;
    }

    public void setDebitCardDetails(Map<String,String> debitCardDetails) {
        this.debitCardDetails = debitCardDetails;
    }


}
```

now in the main class u can return this dto.

something like below

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CardService {

    public CardDetailsDTO serviceCall(List<?> mapDetails) {

        CardDetailsDTO cardDetailsDTO = new CardDetailsDTO();
        final Map<String, String> debitCardDetailsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        final Map<String, String> creditCardDetailsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


        /*code implementation */
        debitCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
        debitCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "BofA");
        debitCardDetailsMap.put("rank", "2");

        cardDetailsDTO.setDebitCardDetails(debitCardDetailsMap);

        creditCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
        creditCardDetailsMap.put("number","23345");
        creditCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "citi");

        cardDetailsDTO.setCreditCardDetails(creditCardDetailsMap);

        return cardDetailsDTO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you would like to do but I would recommend to use OOP way of doing it.

Advantages of OOP approach is, code will be modular, easy to understand, extendable and scalable without impacting existing functionality.

1. Create an abstract class `Card` which can be parent to different types of cards i.e. `DebitCard` and `CreditCard`
2. Create two java classes `DebitCard` and `CreditCard` that extends `Card` each with their own properties (type, number etc), getters-setters and constructors.
3. Have a enum `CardType` that will define a string which defines a card type like `CREDIT_CARD`, `DEBIT_CARD` etc
4. In your serviceCall method instead of having `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, you can have `Map<CardType, List<Card>>` which can hold different type of cards. Populate them as follows ...
5. Given the enum in the map, you can handle each card separately in the `ServiceClass` as follows ...

---

```
public Map<CardType, List<Card>> populateData (){
    Map<CardType, List<Card>> cardMap = new HashMap<CardType, List<Card>>();

    List<Card> debitCards = new LinkedList<Card>();
    debitCards.add(new DebitCard("Visa", "Bofa", "2"));
    cardMap.put(CardType.DEBIT_CARD, debitCards);

    List<Card> creditCards = new LinkedList<Card>();
    creditCards.add(new CreditCard("Visa", "23345", "citi"));
    cardMap.put(CardType.CREDIT_CARD, creditCards);

    return cardMap;
}

public void handleData (Map<CardType, List<Card>> cardMap) {
    if (cardMap.get(CardType.CREDIT_CARD) != 0 && cardMap.get(CardType.CREDIT_CARD).size() > 0)) {
          // do something for credit cards list
    } else if (cardMap.get(CardType.CREDIT_CARD) != 0 && cardMap.get(CardType.DEBIT_CARD).size() > 0)) {
          // do something for debit cards list
    } // have as many else as enum types
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have many ways to do it, I will show few of them.

### Void method

```
public void populateMaps (Map<String, String> debitCardDetailsMap, Map<String, String> creditCardDetailsMap) {
    debitCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
    debitCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "BofA");
    debitCardDetailsMap.put("rank", "2");

    creditCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
    creditCardDetailsMap.put("number","23345");
    creditCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "citi");
}
```

You need to instantiate and pass in the maps from the calling method and this is how you avoid the return type (it will stay void)

### return `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`

```
public Map<String, Map<String, String>> populateMaps() {
    //instantiate the maps
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    final Map<String, String> debitCardDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
    final Map<String, String> creditCardDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();

    //populate the core maps
    debitCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
    debitCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "BofA");
    debitCardDetailsMap.put("rank", "2");

    creditCardDetailsMap.put("type", "VISA");
    creditCardDetailsMap.put("number","23345");
    creditCardDetailsMap.put("bank", "citi");

    //populate the main map
    map.put(debitCardDetailsMap);
    map.put(creditCardDetailsMap);

    return map;
}
```

This way you don't need to instantiate the maps outside this method.

There are more ways to create these maps, but i think the once I've show above is the better once.